# Update Cordova-Crosswalk-Android App to a new Crosswalk version?

Tags: android, html, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

I use the [Crosswalk runtime](https://crosswalk-project.org) to build a [Crosswalk Cordova App for Android](https://crosswalk-project.org/#documentation/cordova)

**How can I update such an app to a new version of crosswalk?**

Comment: just rebuild the app?

Comment: @amirbar what do you mean with rebuild?

Comment: just like you build the first app, build it again with the new version

Comment: @amirbar yes but I do not want to install all the used Cordova plugins again. Is there a way just to change the crosswalk part?

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the new crosswalk project manager (or whatever the official name is) contains not only a `create` script, but also an `update` script.

```
> update
Usage: update <path_to_project> [--shared]
    --shared will use the CordovaLib project directly instead of making a copy.
```

Can't say over how many versions this works, but at least in my most recent attempt it worked quite neatly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have not modified Crosswalk or Cordova directly i.e. are using the CordovaLib as a Library Project and not modified it directly, then...

The **framework** folder that is inside the download from the CrossWalk website contains the Cordova Android project (the "framework" folder). Inside this project is another project, the xwalk_core_library project. You should be able to just swap these two folders with your current versions.

Lastly you will need to import the cordova.js into your app project.